# Publishing Azure Function Using CloudShell

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-shell

I am using CloudShell to publish AzureFunction. I was able to publish the AzureFunction previously but today I am getting this Error while executing the publish command `func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>`

```
Getting site publishing info... 
Creating archive for current directory... 
Performing remote build for functions project. Deleting the old .python_packages directory Uploading 15.91 KB [##############################################################################] 
Remote build in progress, please wait... 
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].build_summary', line 1, position 630.
```

Comment: I have followed this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-create-serverless#code-try-0) and able to create a function using CloudShell

Comment: Could you please provide me the doc which you are following ?

Comment: Were you able to publish the Azure function ??

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-python?tabs=azure-cli%2Cbash%2Cbrowser

Comment: Will work this the doc which you have provided and let you know

Comment: Even I got the same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCIyp.png) while publishing, but Iam able to access the [url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkUwo.png)

Comment: Yeah meet to I am getting error but some how I am able to access.

Comment: Are you publishing to a Linux plan? If so, check out this issue I raised - a lot of people have been hitting it (publishing to Windows OK, just when publishing to Linux): https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/556

Comment: Yes, I am publishing to a Linux plan.